# Mudar dado dentro de um TXT

Tags: python-3.x, batch, txt, bat

Tenho um .txt que precisa de alteração constante por parte do usuário.
gostaria de criar um .bat ou um .py que permitisse o usuário dar input alterando dados do .txt
alguém consegue me dar uma luz??
vou criar um exemplo...

```
     Trabalho: 
       Horas_trabalhadas: 10
       Horas_Extra: 4
       Dia_Folga: Ter
```

set /p horas_trabalhadas= Quantas horas voce trabalhou hoje?:

alguma ideia de manter o mesmo código continuamente alterando o mesmo arquivo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja se é isso que você quer:

```
@echo off

:: Informe o nome do Arquivo aqui:
set Arquivo=Arquivo.txt
echo.
set /p "Horas_Trabalhadas=Informe as horas trabalhadas: "

for /f "tokens=1* usebackq delims=:" %%a in ("%Arquivo%") do (
                                                              IF /i "%%a"=="Horas_trabalhadas" (>>"%Arquivo%.tmp" echo Horas_trabalhadas: %Horas_Trabalhadas%) else (>>"%Arquivo%.tmp" echo %%a:%%b)
                                                             )
del /q "%Arquivo%"
ren "%Arquivo%.tmp" "%Arquivo%"
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]